# Bokeh Not Assigning A Date?

Tags: pandas, datetime, data-analysis, keyerror

I'm having an issue plotting a timeline using Bokeh. The [documentation](https://github.com/microsoft/msticpy/blob/main/docs/notebooks/EventTimeline.ipynb) says that you should be able to reassign the default using '''parse_dates''' but when I create the plot:

```
example = pd.read_csv(
    "exampledataframe.csv",
    parse_dates=["Date"],
    infer_datetime_format=True,
    index_col=0
);
display_timeline(example)
```

I get this error

```
KeyError: "None of [Index(['TimeGenerated'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]
```

Why isn't Bokeh reassigning the index to the "Date" column in my dataframe? I can't find anything about the issue.

Also, please forgive mistakes in terminology. I am a novice in data analysis.

Comment: Can you give a minimal reproducible sample of the data housed in your .csv ?

Comment: Kinda solved? I got the plot working, though inelegantly. I had to change the "date" column name in the CSV to the 'TimeGenerated' default. I'll leave this up to see if anyone else has solutions without having to alter the DF. Can't provide the data btw, though everything there is working.

Comment: I made a proposition/workaround for you in the answers section below.

Comment: FYI this error message is entirely from Pandas. I have removed the `bokeh` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the arguments `names` and `header` in [**`pandas.read_csv`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) to rename the `Date` column :

```
example = pd.read_csv(
    "exampledataframe.csv",
    parse_dates=["Date"],
    infer_datetime_format=True,
    index_col=0,
    names=["TimeGenerated", "...."],
    header=None
);

display_timeline(example)
```

*Make sure to assign/add (by order) in `names` argument the list of the columns names of your .csv.*